# How to test java code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have project created in eclipse.
Can you please guide me how can i test it on Eclipse?
Where can i get the relevant eclipse version and how to do that?

The project file contains the following details:

```xml
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read about Eclipse with JUnit here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 4):

Since Erich Gamma was on the same plane as Kent Beck when JUnit was born, he integrated this tightly into the Eclipse IDE as a standard feature of the JDT.

If you open the help and navigate to

*Java development user guide > Getting Started > Basic tutorial*

there is a nice tutorial tuned to eclipse.

BTW : any version of eclipse will do, since it is in there since as as I can remember, at least since 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest eclipse from the eclipse site.
Eclipse comes with JUnit. Read about JUnit in the junit site. 
It should take you 5 minutes to figure it out from there.

Comment: can you please send me the relevant link?